# Asp.net core stylesheets not being used on pages other than the index

Tags: css, asp.net-core-mvc

What am I overlooking when adding additional pages to my asp.net core mvc project in order for the stylesheets to work?

I have a contact page which works fine when I rename it to index.cshtml, however when I have renamed it back to contact.cshtml which is used as a link on the page, the stylesheets do not work.

Comment: show us _layout.cshtml, do you have minification enabled, is that gulp script running after or before you build?

Comment: Can you show us some code like layout,views etc ?

Comment: I didn't have the stylesheets referenced in _layout.cshtml. Which solved the problem with the formatting, unless I null it, which comes to the problem which is the routing... and the page is looking for the files in /home/images instead of /images...